# codeigniter getting data without foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to select data from two tables 
and then send it back as array to function  
and pass that data array to my view using codeigniter.

My array of values coming from database is like bellow, when I `print_r` it in view

```
Array 
( 
     [0] => stdClass Object 
     ( 
         [task] => Receiving Building Permit 
         [task_status] => 0 
         [date_duration] => 25.08.08 (1 day) 
         [gallery] => 1 
         [download] => 1 
         [project_name] => Investment and Development 
     ) 
     [1] => stdClass Object 
     ( 
         [task] => Back Filling 
         [task_status] => 1 
         [date_duration] => 16.11.08 - 21.11.08 (7 days) 
         [gallery] => 1 
         [download] => 1 
         [project_name] => 
         Investment and Development 
      ) 
 )
```

Actually its return two rows.
If you notice the value of project_name in both rows are same

Now I want to print `project_name` value on top of row then I will repeat the rows with foreach.

How to get `project_name` value before foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the project name you can do `$array[0]->project_name`.